# Using a temperature relay as a fridge temperature control thermostat

Tags: appliances

I have W9RXXMFWQ00 that isn't working anymore unless I hit it, so I'm assuming the thermostat is broken.

A replacement thermostat is 150$ so that is out of the question

I was wondering if anyone ever used a temperature relay such as Siemens 3RS1 or something like that to act as a thermostat?

Comment: Step zero - verify your diagnosis....

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why a device such as the Siemens 3RS1 could not be adapted to control a refrigerator.  I'm assuming you have one on hand as the price of one of these is close to the $150 that you are saying is out of the question.

Keep in mind that this device has no built-in thermometer, so you'll need to add an appropriate one of your own.  Also be aware of the output capacity so that you don't damage it by switching the compressor on and off.

Comment: Yes, I do have a bunch on hand along with thermocouples of all kind. Sorry I forgot to specifify!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had the same thoughts as you but was worried I was forgetting something